# How to download large files in iOS?

Tags: iphone, ios

I'm trying to download files [> 40MB] from web server over HTTP request. To do that I've used the SimpleURLConnection sample provided by the apple. In that sample they only download the image files, so I modified the code to download pdf files and stored it in application's document directory. This is working fine to download small files, but it only download 6.4MB of data if I trying to download large files [>40Mb]. please help me to fix this,

Thank you,

FYI:

code to write file with downloaded data

```
  - (void)connection:(NSURLConnection *)theConnection didReceiveData:(NSData *)data
    // A delegate method called by the NSURLConnection as data arrives.  We just 
    // write the data to the file.
{
    #pragma unused(theConnection)
    NSInteger       dataLength;
    const uint8_t * dataBytes;
    NSInteger       bytesWritten;
    NSInteger       bytesWrittenSoFar;

    assert(theConnection == self.connection);

    dataLength = [data length];
    dataBytes  = [data bytes];

    bytesWrittenSoFar = 0;
    do {
        bytesWritten = [self.fileStream write:&dataBytes[bytesWrittenSoFar] maxLength:dataLength - bytesWrittenSoFar];
        assert(bytesWritten != 0);
        if (bytesWritten == -1) {
            [self _stopReceiveWithStatus:@"File write error"];
            break;
        } else {
            bytesWrittenSoFar += bytesWritten;
        }
    } while (bytesWrittenSoFar != dataLength);
}
```

Comment: Have you got any debug information? Oh, and the `assert(theConnection == self.connection)` is so terrible that this code is doomed to crash if you use multiple connections. Use `if (theConnection != self.connection) { return; }` instead.

Answer (score 7):

Don't reinvent the wheel!
ASIHTTP has you covered, [see there](http://allseeing-i.com/ASIHTTPRequest/How-to-use#downloading_the_response_directly_to_a_file). There's a specific option to download directly to file.

Comment: On Stackoverflow, the answer to about 1 out of 20 newbie questions is "Use ASIHttpRequest" ... !

Comment: But it's just the way it is - it's the simplest solution to all these download problems :)

Answer (score 2):

ASIHTTP is no longer in active development as of September 2011. I've found that [RestKit](http://restkit.org/) is a good alternative in many cases, however it lacks many features of ASI such as download pausing and resuming.

Comment: Any update on this thread. I try to find a way to download big files with resume feature...(without using ASI)..