# Use CFNetwork to download a file

Tags: objective-c, cfnetwork

I want to use ios basic networking scheme CFNetwork to download a file.I have used NSURLConnection but i want to explore the low level api.Any tutorials or sample codes to start?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I'd take a look at [Apple's documentation](http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#documentation/Networking/Conceptual/CFNetwork/Introduction/Introduction.html) for CFNetwork as a good start. That should give you an idea of whats available within the framework. 
What are you downloading from? E.g. ftp server

If you are downloading from an ftp server, Apple provide a sample code which provides upload/download/listing of an ftp server.

Comment: I need to download fro an HTTP Server

Comment: check out http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6322597/how-to-download-large-files-in-ios

Comment: i think it is a usual nsurlconnection delegate to download file.I am looking for the corresponding cfnetwork alternative.